# Firebase (firestore) rules: ensure update only if another document is updated (FieldValue increase)?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm trying to create a `stats` doc inside a collection and I want to allow updating it only when another doc is updated inside this same collection (batch write, in short). Is there any way to ensure another doc is being updated during this request?

The reason I'm even thinking about allowing it *client-side* is due to this source: [Keep a Count of Documents in a Collection](https://fireship.io/snippets/firestore-increment-tips/#keep-a-count-of-documents-in-a-collection).

Any better way to get a count of documents? (I don't care if it's an actual call to REST API instead of through the SDK).

I am validating if the `stats` are properly updated based on the request data received on that other doc (private => public, public => private, created, deleted ...), since I know the exact **path** for the `stats` document, *obviously*.

But I have no idea how to ensure the `stats` can only get updated when/if another document does (*besides the obvious, where I pass an ID of that document alongside*).

A short version for my rules is:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }
    match /stories/---STATS--- {
      allow read;
      allow create, update;
    }

    match /stories/{storyId} {
      allow read: if isPublic() || isAuthor();
      allow create: if
        isSignedIn() &&
        updatedStats() &&
        validateCreate();

      function updatedStats() {
        return getAfterStats().updatedAt == request.time;
      }
      function validateCreate() {
        return
          ( // Created public
            new().public &&
            isIncreaseN() &&
            isIncreaseNAll()
          ) ||
          ( // Created private
            !new().public &&
            isUntouchedN() &&
            isIncreaseNAll()
          );
      }
      // COUNTERS
      function isStats() {
        return exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/stories/---STATS---);
      }
      function getStats() {
        return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/stories/---STATS---).data;
      }
      function getAfterStats() {
        return getAfter(/databases/$(database)/documents/stories/---STATS---).data;
      }
      // n
      function isIncreaseN() {
        return  (!isStats() && getAfterStats().n == 1) ||
                (!getStats().keys().hasAll(['n']) && getAfterStats().n == 1) ||
                (getStats().n +1 == getAfterStats().n);
      }
      function isUntouchedN() {
        return  (!isStats() && !getAfterStats().keys().hasAll(['n'])) ||
                (!getStats().keys().hasAll(['n']) && !getAfterStats().keys().hasAll(['n'])) ||
                (getStats().n == getAfterStats().n);
      }
      // nAll
      function isIncreaseNAll() {
        return  (!isStats() && getAfterStats().nAll == 1) ||
                (!getStats().hasAll(['nAll']) && getAfterStats().nAll == 1) ||
                (getStats().nAll +1 == getAfterStats().nAll);
      }
  }
}

// GETTERS
function new() {
  return request.resource.data;
}
function cur() {
  return resource.data;
}
function auth() {
  return request.auth;
}

// MISC
function isSingedIn() {
  return auth() != null;
}
```

I have some more validation rules for `stats` file, like allowing only certain fields to exist, only allowing increments/decrements by 1, etc., but nothing to actually prevent increasing this even when not touching any actual `story`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Firebase security rules, it's not possible to know if some arbitrary document in a collection has changed in tandem with another document.  You have to know the full paths of all the documents in the batch write in order to be able to see if they both changed consistently.

Comment: Then I guess I'll have to pass the ID along as well. I'll wait a few more days, in case some other answer crops up, before accepting it as final. Thanks for fast response.